# Sharp/high-pitch squeaks from the steering wheel

Tags: toyota, steering-wheel, squeaking

I have a 2019 Toyota Corolla Hybrid. Sometimes I hear high-pitch squeaky noise from the steering wheel. Somebody else had this exact problem as shown in this video: https://youtu.be/ZutsVBX5jCs Is this something to worry about? What could it be? Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a piece of trim has moved - take it in under warranty.